# How do I run two command in Lambda Function

Tags: lambda

Currently I have this script in my lambda function

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import json
import boto3

region=['ap-southeast-1']
instance1 = 'i-XXXXXXXXXX'
instance2 = 'i-XXXXXXXXXX'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # boto3 client
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
    response = ssm_client.send_command(InstanceIds=[instance1],DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",Parameters={'commands': ['aws s3 sync cd/var/www/html s3://bucketname/']}, )
    response2 = ssm_client.send_command(InstanceIds=[instance2],DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",Parameters={'commands': ['aws s3 sync s3://bucketname /var/www/html/']}, )

    command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
    command_id2 = response2['Command']['CommandId']
    
    time.sleep(60)

    output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(CommandId=command_id,InstanceId=instance1,)
    output2 = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(CommandId=command_id2,InstanceId=instance2,)

   
    print(output)
    print(output2)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Done!')
    }
```

the result is successful. but they run command at the same time. I want the second command run after sync to s3 are done.

What i want to do is:

instance1 > s3

after sync done

s3 > instance2

the reason i want to do this because instance1 cannot sync to instance2 for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario when you have a sequence of execution, I would say you may use AWS step functions:

1- create two separated lambda functions, one for instance1 > s3, and the second for s3 > instance2.

2- create AWS Step Functions to run a serverless workflow that coordinates the two AWS Lambda functions.

This  [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-creating-lambda-state-machine.html) shows how to create function step state uses lambda